# PHP regex with newlines and html tags

Tags: php, regex

I know this might be not that hard to do but i never learned regex, and i know this is kinda stupid because it has the power to rescue you from lots of bad situations.

Anyway my question is, i try to preg_replace a html string with

```
</p><br />(maybe newline here)
<p>
```

to

```
</p>(can contain newline or not, does not matter)
<p>
```

There are newlines and also it may contain a space before newline.

Thanks for your help, stackoverflow is the best!

Comment: [Do **Not** use regex to parse HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/4934172).

Comment: ... but is it `<br>` `<br/>`, `<br />`, `<BR>`, `<BR/>` or `<BR />` ? That's why manipulating HTML with RegEx is generally a terrible idea.

Comment: While there is a popular belief on SO that - in effect - Regex should never touch HTML; [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1733489/3536236) gives a more useful clarification of the situation. If you have a clear concrete concept of what you're looking for and of the syntax of the subject string them Regex should work fine for you.

Comment: Please add the `preg_replace` you tried.

Comment: Anyway, what you seem to ask for is a mere `str_replace('<br />', '', $s)`

Comment: I already tried str_replace, it does not work for my situation. I'm not going to use this before general html output, only need it for changing an admin panel and try to use the content from the older one with exact copy of    </p><br />
    <p> everywhere

Comment: Also suggested questions has nothing to do with what i'm looking for, thanks anyway